# Do not want to copy on write

Tags: c++, qt

I've got class member:

```
QStringList list;
```

How to avoid copying-on-write when returning this member and updating it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Copying-on-write"? Usually this refers to an optimization for copying as late as possible (see e.g. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-On-Write). Seems you'd be more correct if you just leave out the "on write"

Comment: Do you want the update in the caller to be seen in your object? Or what is it that you want to avoid?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the first one you've mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You could return a reference or a pointer to it:

```
QStringList& getList() {
    return list;
}
```

This would return just a reference to your list. But essentially this would be the same as declaring `list` public.

**EDIT**

This should work:

```
MyClass obj;

obj.getList().push_back("someStr");
```

Comment: with this approach I'm getting errors about incorrect initialization of ref QStringList

Answer (score 1):

or you could get it by reference:

```
QStringList& LIST = myClass.list;
```